# Datetime with AM/PM rconversion to standard format into database in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon, laravel-5.8

I've a date in the following format

```
$date = "6.17.2019 12:00:00 AM."
```

I need to convert this into Y-m-d h:i:s.
I tried the following line of code,

```
$regdate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

But it results in error.

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (6.17.2019 12:00:00 AM.) at position 7 (1): Unexpected character"

Desired output is :

> 2019-06-17 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo can change format to carbon then can be change to any format.

```
$date = "6.17.2019 12:00:00 AM.";

        $regdate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m.d.Y h:i:s A.', '6.17.2019 12:00:00 AM.');
        $regdate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($regdate)->format('Y-m-d');
        echo $regdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume whatever this Carbon thing is extends the PHP DateTime class?

Use `createFromFormat()`

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s A.', '6.17.2019 12:00:00 AM.');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

which will give you:

```
2020-05-06 00:00:00
```

Check it out here https://3v4l.org/g53Xp

And read up on PHP's DateTime class https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: That's the wrong format. You get `2020-05-06` when inputting `6.17.2019`. That's completely off.  The `createFromFormat()`-format should be `'n.j.Y H:i:s A.'` (swapped day and month and without leading zeros)

Comment: well spotted Magnus, didnt see the `d` and `m` were the wrong way around